# how to find path to a div plus the width and height of the content

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to i get the path to the content plus the width and height of it using js or jquery

so if you have

Home |  People | Help | Store | Support

and you click on Home  it will show

```
div.sys_main_menu > div.sys_mm >
div.sys_mm_cnt.bx-def-margin-sec-leftright >
table.topMenu > tbody > tr > td.top > a.top_link >
span.down.bx-def-padding-sec-leftright 54px > 38px
```

so path plus width and height of the content

thank you

Comment: What do you mean by path to content?

Comment: @Gary like  `div.menu > p` so Home would be in <p> Home </p>

Comment: You can use `parent()`, `width()`, `className` to find all of this. What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: Why do you need the full path?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming there is some kind of jquery or js action on Home click. One click you just need to find current tag and class, and go reverse through the tree adding pertinent information.

```js
$('.down').on('click',function(){
   var child=$(this);
    var parent=child.parent().prop('className');
    var tree=[];
    tree.push(child.css('width'));
    tree.push(child.css('height'));
    tree.push(child.prop('className'));
    tree.push(child.prop('tagName'));
    tree.push(parent);
    while(child.parent().hasClass('sys_main_menu') != true){
        child=child.parent();
        if(child.parent().prop('className')!='')
            parent=child.parent().prop('className');
        tree.push(child.prop('tagName'));
        tree.push(parent);
    }
    child=child.parent();
    parent=child.parent().prop('className');
    tree.push(child.prop('tagName'));
 var path='';
    for(i=tree.length-1;i>=0;i--){  
  path=path+tree[i];
  if(i>0)
  path=path+'>';
    }
 console.log(path);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sys_main_menu"> 
    <div class="sys_mm"> 
        <div class="sys_mm_cnt bx-def-margin-sec-leftright">
            <table class="topMenu">
                <tbody> 
                    <tr>
                        <td class="top">
                            <a class="top_link">
                                <span class="down bx-def-padding-sec-leftright" style="width:54px;height=38px">
                                    Home
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```